# Integration of Struts2 and birt report

Tags: java, struts2, birt

Ingtigration of birt reprot and struts2

this is for struts2 ,hibernate and Birt viewer environment.

please provide solution for integration of struts 2 and birtviwer.

Answer (score 0):

BIRT has inbuilt library for ReportDesigner and ReportServices.

I insist , you first understand the various layers in BIRT .

[image]

Basically , you can import these libraries into your structs controller and call the library API functions to compute logics, form the docs( html,pdf,charts etc )  and generate and display the reports.

For the  BIRT Designer , you can install BIRT Report Designer Plugin in eclipse . This adds a layer to your eclipse where you can first design the report layout and configure database connections.

This designer , gives your ***.rptdesign*** file.

These rptdesign files are then request called from the Report Service(to be called from  controller) in DEAPI.

Refer the following blog .

http://esitnikov.blogspot.com/2010/01/birt-best-practice_5227.html